# Div overlays sibling element and has extra height for no apparent reason

Tags: php, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

Hi I'm having a problem with some WordPress theme development. I'm working with Underscores to make my own theme, and I've integrated Foundation 5. My vision is to have an off-canvas site menu that comes down from the top. Logically, I want to move the nav above the header and site description, instead of the default of it being below, so I'm editing header.php. Here's the code that's in between the header tags :

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'ibeyi' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Here is the HTML that it is spitting out (from Chrome dev tools):

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
        <div class="menu"><!--menu truncated for sake of brevity; your regular ul, li scene--></div>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    <div class="site-branding">
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/ibeyi_theme/" rel="home">Ibeyi Theme</a></h1>
                    <p class="site-description">Just another WordPress site</p>
    </div><!-- .site-branding -->   
</header>
```

You can see that I moved  out of its previous location, which was inside of div.site-branding. Yet for some reason when I apply this styling

```
.site-branding{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

It effects gives nav a grey background! For whatever reason, nav is still acting as though it is in .site-branding! Technically I can work around this by styling a bunch of exceptions for nav specifically, but it seems like it would be easier to try to find out why this is happening. I don't entirely understand what WP PHP is spitting out all the time, so maybe that has something to do with it. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF1BC.png)

UPDATE: From the comments we have deduced that the nav element itself does not have lightgrey defined as its background-color. Instead, for some reason, the .site-branding div seems to perpetually extend to the top. .site-branding is picking up more height than it needs to, although it has no margin or padding and it is not inheriting its height from its parent element, since they have slightly different heights. To illustrate how the div will reach to the top no matter what, here is a screenshot of my situation with .site-branding's height decreased:

[Screenshot—reduced height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xRhe.png)

Both nav and .site-branding are position:static, and do exit off the top of the page when scrolling down, as they should. For some reason its stuck to the top, although it acts just like a static element should when scrolling. It even goes so far as to let its content spill out the bottom just so it can reach all the way up to the top. One last interesting note: if I give it a top-margin it will come off the top, but that's the only way I've been able to do it so far and it seems like it's a fix that just avoids the problem. I want to find out why it's doing what it's doing.

Still a mystery. I turns out that I'm not even going to be using this navigation scheme but I'm really curious as to why this is happening and would like to know, just in case I run into a problem like it in the future.

Comment: Please post html and css as well, php is not of much use here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. What html and css would you like me to post?

Comment: Of your header that you're trying to affect. Give html that this php will create, and post relevant css.

Comment: Okay just put it in; just the one css style that I already gave is the only one relevant to the header that I have applied (I haven't gotten to styling it yet; I was just starting when I ran into this problem).

Comment: If you haven't styled it yet, then what is the css for nav? And for other divs? Did you defined their positions?

Comment: Not yet. I've merely moved the code in between the <nav> tags out of the .site-branding div so that it shows above the title of the website. I'm just puzzled as to why any css edits I make to .site-branding is still affecting the nav even though it's not in that div anymore.

Comment: When you define your css, then you'll see how it behaves. You haven't done any styling to your elements and you wonder why this happens? Put `nav{display:block;}` or `nav{display:inline-block; width:100%}`, and `.site-branding{display:block;}`, and see what happens

Comment: Nothing changed. Now what should I do?

Comment: One thing is not clear to me. Even if you don't add any other css, the `nav` is not in the `.site-branding`, it's out of it: https://jsfiddle.net/vrmbuhyn/

Comment: Exactly! That's why I'm so confused, haha! I'll add a screenshot just to prove that I'm not crazy.

Comment: Okay I added a screenshot. Weird, right?

Comment: Then there must be something else that's giving it the gray background. Did you try inspecting your site? F12, or right click on the element and click inspect element. Then go through your DOM, and see what gives this gray background.

Comment: Okay; this is still weird but i've made some progress. the <nav> itself does not have any background color. However, it turns out that for some reason div.site-branding's height is extending all the way up into the top. I found a few box-sizing:inherit classes that might be causing the problem, but even if I change it to box-sizing:inital, it doesn't fix it. Two more interesting things: If I manually lower the height in dev tools, it takes off of the bottom, therefore not encompassing the content it holds. Also, If I give margin-top:30px to .box-sizing, it finally gets the grey out of the nav

Comment: It turns out I'm actually not going to use this form of navigation, but I'm just really curious now.

Comment: Okay... here's a little more. The div.site-branding has a different height than its parent element, so box-sizing shouldn't have anything to do with it. But like I mentioned, if I decrease the height on div.site-branding, the height comes off the bottom, making the content spill out of the bottom of the div and still encompassing the <nav> I'll post a screenshot and show you what it looks like.

Comment: what are the positionings of the elements? If the `.site-branding` is fixed this would explain a lot...

Comment: See I thought about that too. Nav and .site-branding have position:static. Where is the .site-branding even picking up the extra height? It's like for some reason has to reach all the way up to the top. Is there some attribute that does something like that?

Comment: It's hard to tell without inspecting

Comment: Hmm, yeah I could totally see that. I've already done a fair amount of that myself but haven't found anything. What specifically should I be looking for? Other than a defined height or a box-sizing attribute, are there other things that would cause additional height?

Comment: `display` and `position` properties would come to my mind first.